# JQuery: any browsing divs plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Imagine i have a grid of 5x5 divs
and the first one is selected with class="selected"

there is any plugin ready so i can use my keyboard arrows to navigate left/right up down in that grid?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/177538)

Comment: Hi Francesco, my suggestion is to use Google to see if you can find something that might work. If you then find some code that you're stuck on, definitely come back and see us and we'll be happy to help with any specific questions you may have. Aside from that, StackOverflow isn't really a good platform for recommendation or referral questions. Alternatively, try it yourself with keypress! I think you could possibly do this *without* a plugin. Feel free to post any code you have and ask specific questions. I'd love to help; sounds like a fun problem. Good luck!

Comment: I don't even think you need a plugin for this. You can easily build your own.

Comment: actually there was one but i cant find the source http://mike-hostetler.com/jquery-keyboard-navigation-plugin

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any plugins that provide this functionality, but it is a relatively simple and fun problem so I gave it a shot.

For the HTML, structure your grid like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="boxrow">
    <div class="box selected"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxrow">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxrow">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For the styling, here is something simple to get you started:

```
.box {
  height: 5px;
  width:5px;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 1px;
  float: left;
}

.selected {
  background-color: blue;
}

.boxrow {
  clear: both;
}​
```

And finally, here is the Javascript. You can turn this into a plugin if you want to expand the functionality.

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {

    var selected = $('.selected');
    var row = selected.parent('.boxrow');
    var index = row.children('.box').index(selected);

    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 37: // left
        if (selected.prev('.box').length != 0)
          selected.removeClass('selected').prev('.box').addClass('selected');
        break;
      case 38: // up
        var prevRow = row.prev('.boxrow');
        if (prevRow.length != 0) {
          selected.removeClass('selected');
          prevRow.children('.box').eq(index).addClass('selected');
        }
        break;
      case 39: // right
        if (selected.next('.box').length != 0) 
          selected.removeClass('selected').next('.box').addClass('selected');
        break;
      case 40: // down
        var nextRow = row.next('.boxrow');
        if (nextRow.length != 0) {
          selected.removeClass('selected');
          nextRow.children('.box').eq(index).addClass('selected');
        }
        break;
    }

});​
```

Have fun and hope you find this useful.

**Here is a 
[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gizmovation/x4f99/).**